# How to split one column with x different values into 2 columns (with only one value each) and several rows

Tags: python, pandas

Good morning everyone,

This is my first post and I am struggling here with a problem of values that follows a hierarchy, so order is important in my problem, I will try to be as clear as I can, thank you very much for your help:

I have a data frame with userID (each row representing a company with a unique userID) with a "job" column where all different teams of the company are separated with a "/" . Hierarchy here is important so first team is the head of the company (ex: 1CEO/ 2DG / 1DA ...) knowing that I don"t always have the same nb of teams in each companies. I would like to split the job column and have for each row, the parent team and the child team (parent value = id of the child team)

So I would like to have a new df with
MasterteamID    TeamID
1CEO              2DG
2DG               1DA

The child team being the parent team of the following team, so each rows starts with the 2nd value of the previous row.

I tried several things here, spited the column and have each team in a column, or each team in a row grouped by user ID. But impossible to make them in only 2 columns then with a print-child hierarchy.

Do you have any idea?
Here is an example of what I am trying to do :

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"userID":"01234532","username":"532","job":["1DG/11 DGDR/100 DA"]})
test
```

and I would like to have that for all companies in the same order

```
solution = {"MasterTeamID":["1DG", "11 DGDR"], "TeamID":["11 DGDR","100 DA"]}
solution = pd.DataFrame(solution)
solution
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: can you provide a more conrcret example? like the original dt with rows and the expected output

Comment: Hi, I tried to edit the post and put actual values in the test DataFrame, which I have at the beginning, and the solution, which I am trying to have at the end. Can you have the DataFrame with values now? and thank you very much by the way!!

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-split-strings-into-two-list-columns-using-str-split/ may be relevant. Also look into python sorting and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html My own approach would be to first write down exactly what you want to do using a for-loop over the rows, with Python List- and String-manipulation functions, and then try to find pandas / DataFrame / numpy equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

my code is split your column like this
**['1CEO','2DG','2DG','1DA']**

```
for row in test['job'].str.split('/'):
    print(row) #['1CEO','2DG','2DG','1DA']
    break
```

*test['job'].str.split('/') 

split every cell in column*